# Benefit to user of Creating new Tag

Tags: discussion, tags, reputation, markdown-preview

I know *how* to create a new Tag, but what is benefit to me if I do create one?

I know it will help to specify the problem category, but what other benefits does a Tag owner get?

Comment: For every 100 tags you create, you get a cookie :) Seriously now, what benefit, other than helping organize the site, did you expect? A good tag will get you a [silver Taxonomist badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist), isn't it enough?

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox - Is that like the cake for 10k rep?

Comment: @Oded No, the cookie is not a lie! (^_-)

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox: I've got 15 cookies from Stack Overflow, and I didn't even create a tag! :)

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox: you always have best guidance..thank you :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also help users who are unable to create new (valid) tags ([/privileges/create-tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags)) which provides the benefit of a warm fuzzy feeling in helping them out.

Answer (score 3):

> I know it will help to specify problem category

Is that not benefit enough?

By tagging the question, chances of it getting the attention of people interested in that kind of thing is greater - simply looking at the tags people can see if they think they can or cannot help. This in turn means that you have a better chance of getting an answer, and a better answer at that.

If the tag is used in 50 and more questions, you get the [taxonomist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist) badge.

Comment: Its enough.But i was meant that was I am missing some corner of knowledge about this.

Comment: Hmm funny you guys took the time to answer this mans question yet you didn't up vote it?  Why is that?  You expect him to accept one of your answers but you don't do the courtesy of marking his as a good question

Answer (score 1):

What benefit do you have to answer questions and solve other people's problems?

If that answers your question - you'll get a badge if you create a good tag: [Taxonomist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist). Now, is that a benefit and what kind of a benefit would you expect is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Its enough.But i was meant that was I am missing some corner of knowledge about this.